# App rejected from Google Play (not compliant with one or more of our Developer Policies)

Tags: android, google-play, publish, firebase-analytics, disclosure

"Your app is uploading users' Installed Application information to **https://cloudconfig.googleapis.com** without a prominent disclosure."

I'm getting the above message, but my app is only using Firebase analytics. Do we need to show disclosure even for google apis?

Couldn't understand what's the fix here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Analytics SDK depend on Google Play Services, which Google requires that you disclose in your privacy policy. You could check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google-play-services-required-recommended) the list of the components that uses Google Play Services in Firebase.